# Global shortcuts now require to open specific app (Divvy, Rectangle, aText) before triggering action

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, window-manager

I've been using two utility apps many times a day for the past 10 years across various versions of macOS: [Divvy](https://mizage.com/divvy) (a window manager similar to [Rectangle](https://rectangleapp.com)) and [aText](https://trankynam.com/atext/) (a text expansion app similar to [TextExpander](https://textexpander.com)).

I used to be able to type `@@` anywhere and it would expand to my email address, and I could press option-shift-Z to make a window full-screen.

Since around June or July 2021 (I keep my M1 Mac up to date, so maybe there was an update in the OS or these apps?), I started noticing that **none of my ~10 text expansion shortcuts would work unless I launched the aText app first then retried the shortcut** (the app is always running, but I need to re-launch it using Alfred/Spotlight).

Same thing for my ~5 window management shortcuts: **I have to "launch" Divvy, even though it's alway running, for the global shortcuts to trigger anything**.

I tried replacing Divvy with Rectangle but got exactly the same issue: if I run a text expansion shortcut, I then have to launch Rectangle for the window management shortcuts to run, and then I'd have to launch aText for the text expansion shortcuts to run. I fully uninstalled Divvy then re-installed it in the process and still got the same issue.

What is going on? Is this a symptom of a bad macOS configuration on my end or a change in how events are managed in the OS? Outdated applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As often with StackExchange, I found and solved the issue shortly after asking the question!

- I have a broken version of aText from June 2021 that stopped auto-updating
- Running a Divvy or Rectangle "global" shortcut would be intercepted by aText (so not triggering the window management action) then kill aText, as observed using Activity Monitor
- I'd have to re-run the window management shortcut for it to reach Divvy, now that aText wasn't running ("launching" Divvy was just a placebo)
- I'd have to re-launch aText for it to be able to expand text

I manually downloaded the latest aText version and everything works just like before June 2021.